# Is it possible to integrate a DropDownList control into CrystalReportViewer's Toolbar?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, drop-down-menu, toolbar

I have designed a Crystal Report using ASP.NET, now i want to integrate a DropDownList Control into CrystalReportViewer's toolbar along with export, print, zoom buttons.
I wrote following line of code to add it but DropDownList wasn't visible anywhere inside ReportViewer

> `myReportViewer.Controls.Add(myDropDownList);`

what should be done for this?

Comment: You can't modify that, you can write your own toolbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible. You would need to create your own toolbar and hide the default Crystal viewer toolbar icons/features you replace.